# How do I use explode after NOT IN in this query

Tags: codeigniter-3

```
$sql="  SELECT  * 
        FROM mt_volunteer_shift 
        WHERE  volunteer_shift_sale_id =".$value['registered_sale_sale_id'] . " 
        AND volunteer_shift_id NOT IN".$value['registered_sale_volunteer_id']; 

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$active_volunteer =  $query->result_array();
```

Comment: could you please explain what you mean with "*use explode after NOT IN*"?

Comment: i want use explode in this query  after Not IN bcs my value is dynamic in query so I tired to use explode can you help me?

Comment: Please share some more details, as in [mre]

Comment: Please read: [Query Bindings](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#query-bindings) and mainly, use the [Query Builder Class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html), since you are using the Codeigniter framework

Comment: i already check missing string but its not working I want to use explode bcs my id is in array

Comment: [where_not_in()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=#CI_DB_query_builder::where_not_in), anyway without showing your arrays, anyone can just guess

Comment: $sql="SELECT  * FROM mt_volunteer_shift WHERE  volunteer_shift_sale_id =".$value['registered_sale_sale_id'] . " AND volunteer_shift_id where_not_in".$value['registered_sale_volunteer_id'];
can you see this is that correct

Comment: Please read about the PHP function [explode](https://www.php.net/explode), and then use [edit] to add info to your question why you want to use explode.

Answer (score 1):

For example You can use like below format.

```
$registered_sale_volunteer_id= explode(',', $variable);

 $sql= "SELECT * FROM mt_volunteer_shift WHERE volunteer_shift_sale_id =".$registered_sale_sale_id ." 
AND volunteer_shift_id NOT IN (".$registered_sale_volunteer_id.")";
```

Comment: its not working

Comment:  You have to wait till the fuse is burned completely....